# Bootstrap - background on container fix

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have big problem with background property on fluid container in bootstrap 4. How can I fix the text/ background overlapping on mobile version on this site - http://176.32.230.8/finsburymedia-demos.com/legal_fund/
/on mobile version /

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your background style for example (notice the last line):

```
.fcrow1 {
    background-color: #F7F7F7;
    background-image: url(../img/gold.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 50%;
}
```

But maybe your image in the background should be a higher image.

Comment: The question is: what do you want with the background on smaller screen? Where should the image go?

Comment: I want background to be bellow or above the text content on smaller screen

Comment: Then, I think, you should try inside of your `.container-fluid` a simple `.row` and two `.col-sm-6` in it (maybe the `sm` can be `md`, `xs` or `lg` too). The left one with the background and right one with the text. That's the easiest solution.